# Why doesn't this fill the full maze/make interesting mazes?

Tags: c++, maze

I am using c++ to design a recursive maze generator. My issue currently is that the code nearly never makes a maze that fills the entire area for the maze. It also seems to remove the edges of the maze despite my InBounds() function. Lastly, the mazes are often uninteresting/consist of very few actual passages. Please let me know if you can see why?

```
#include "maze-gen.h"
#include <time.h>

// Define maze constructor taking in height,width, and
// filling array with 1s
Maze::Maze(int x, int y) {
    width = x;
    height = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            maze_arr[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }
}

// Define output as outputting each cell separated by " "
// New rows on new lines
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Maze& m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.width; j++) {
            os << m.maze_arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}

//Check if next coords to visit are in bounds
bool Maze::InBounds(int x, int y) {
    if (x > 0 && x < width-1) {
        if (y > 0 && y < height-1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Maze::GenerateMaze(int x, int y) {
    //Set point currently at to 0
    maze_arr[y][x] = ' ';

    //Create array of 4 dir and shuffle
    int dirs[4];
    dirs[0] = N;
    dirs[1] = E;
    dirs[2] = S;
    dirs[3] = W;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int seed = rand() % 4;

        int temp = dirs[seed];
        dirs[seed] = dirs[i];
        dirs[i] = temp;
    }

    int travelX, travelY = 0;
    for (int i : dirs) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                y += 2;
                if (InBounds(x,y)) {
                    if (maze_arr[y][x] != ' ') {
                        maze_arr[y-1][x] = ' ';
                        GenerateMaze(x,y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                x += 2;
                if (InBounds(x,y)) {
                    if (maze_arr[y][x] != ' ') {
                        maze_arr[y][x-1] = ' ';
                        GenerateMaze(x,y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                y -= 2;
                if (InBounds(x,y)) {
                    if (maze_arr[y][x] != ' ') {
                        maze_arr[y+1][x] = ' ';
                        GenerateMaze(x,y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                x -= 2;
                if (InBounds(x,y)) {
                    if (maze_arr[y][x] != ' ') {
                        maze_arr[y][x+1] = ' ';
                        GenerateMaze(x,y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Maze m = Maze(10,10);
    srand(time(0));

    m.GenerateMaze(1,1);

    std::cout << m;

    return 0;
}
```

[An example of the mazes it usually produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjs0.png)

[An example of the desired output from someone else's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gag9G.png)

Comment: My debugger is disabled at the moment.  Can you please use a debugger on your code and post the results, as text?  Be sure to indicate which statement is causing the issue.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added a link to a screenshot of its typical output. I've also added a screenshot of the desired effect. I can't show debugging results because there isn't actually any errors, it seems to just have some sort of issue.

Comment: Links are not trustworthy.  Paste the image if necessary.  Prefer to paste the output as text. Images don't scale as well as text.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 
# # # # #   # # # #
#       #   # # # #
# # #   # # # # # # 
#       # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #

Sorry, new to SO and not sure how to have new lines in the comment so i will add to the post

Comment: Comments are deliberately stupid to force people to put anything important or complex in questions and answers.

Comment: Edits are made to posts, not to the comments.  Look at your comment.  Pasted text can line up and can be indented.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a problematic line in the code. More likely a problematic algorithm. Stepping through the code with a debugger to see what sorts of decisions it makes and the conditions under which it makes them will likely be more useful than a bug hunt. If you are adapting someone else's code, make sure you fully understand the behaviour the code describes.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you have an error in your program in which you are updating `x` or `y` in the recursive step even if the new (x,y) location fails the validity check. Basically change the four cases like

```
y += 2;
if (InBounds(x, y)) {
    if (maze_arr[y][x] != ' ') {
        maze_arr[y - 1][x] = ' ';
        GenerateMaze(x, y);
    }
}
```

to

```
if (InBounds(x, y+2)) {
    if (maze_arr[y+2][x] != ' ') {
        y += 2;
        maze_arr[y - 1][x] = ' ';
        GenerateMaze(x, y);
    }
}
```

or something equivalent.

That will get you much better results. However, you still have the algorithmic problem that there is nothing guaranteeing your program will return full mazes. It is likely to return incomplete mazes as the traversal maybe intersect itself and just drop out of recursion in too many places to fill the whole array.

Typically what you want to do to generate a random maze is maintain a data structure containing the "frontier cells", cells of the array that have not been added to the maze yet but that are adjacent to a cell that has been added to the maze. You iteratively select a random frontier cell, join it to the maze, delete it from the frontier set, and add any new frontier cells to the frontier set created by the new addition to the maze. You can then terminate iteration when the frontier set is empty and are guaranteed a complete maze.